Expanding $\sin(ab)$ in terms of $\sin a$ and $\sin b$.
Motivation behind the question: I've wondered since grade 10 that if $\sin(a+b),\sin(a-b)$ have formulas in terms of $\sin(a)$ and $\sin(b)$, then why not $\sin(ab)$. But I couldn't find any such information sadly.
My attempt:-
$$\sin(ab)=\sin\bigg(\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}-\frac{(a-b)^2}{4}\bigg)$$
This can be expanded as
$$\sin \bigg(\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg)^2\cos \bigg(\frac{a-b}{2}\bigg)^2-\cos \bigg(\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg)^2\sin \bigg(\frac{a-b}{2}\bigg)^2$$
Now even if I try to expand the squares, I get something in the form of $\sin(a^2)$, and thus I can't run from multiplication.
Any help, or closed form solution will be greatly appreciated.

Here is an opinion that an answer does not exist: https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-know-that-a-product-rule-for-sine-doesnt-exist-I-mean-sin-ab

@RedFive the next reply in that post answers my question somehow, with some weird name polynomials

This question has been asked on Math.SE a few times. For instance, see here and here, which I found with a site search for sin(xy) identity. The short answer for there being no "simple" formula is that $\sin a$ and $\sin b$ are $2\pi$-periodic in both $a$ and $b$ individually, but (unless $a$ or $b$ is an integer) $\sin(ab)$ is not.

There is quite a bit in this question beyond the immediate search for an identity. Euler's formula looks like the obvious approach, even if it doesn't seem to lead very far yet.

Thanks @Blue. They are interesting reads and having read them I'm inclined to agree, there is no "simple" formula. Whether or not there is a simple reason for this... probably doesn't matter though.

@RedFive: The simple reason is periodicity. If $$\sin(xy)=f(\sin x, \cos x, \sin y, \cos y)$$ for some function $f$ of trig functions, then the substitution $x\to x+2\pi$ leaves the right-hand side unchanged but turns the left-hand side into $$\sin((x+2\pi)y)=\sin(xy+2y\pi)$$ which differs from $\sin(xy)$ unless $y$ is an integer.

$\sin(ab) = 3 \sin(\frac{ab}{3})-4 \sin^3(\frac{ab}{3})$

@wasu Oh my. In that case $\sin(ab)=2\sin\frac{ab}{2}\cos\frac{ab}{2}$

@Gwen yes, I commented that on Dan's answer.

Your attempt works, but I'm assuming you're in search of a formula which isolates variables $a$ and $b$.
We can derive such a formula for these by De Moivre's Theorem.
$$r^n(\cos(nb) + i\sin(nb))^a = r(\cos(ab)+i\sin(ab))^n$$
Hence, rewriting this in terms of $\cos(ab)$ and $\sin(ab)$, we get:
$$\cos(ab)+i\sin(ab) = (\cos(b) + i\sin(b))^a$$
Assuming $a$ is a positive integer, we get, by applying the Binomial Theorem,
$$(\cos(b) + i\sin(b))^a=[\cos^a(b)+\frac{a(a-1)}{1\cdot2}\cos^{a-2}(b)\sin^2(b)+\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}\cos^{a-4}(b)\sin^4(b)]\dots+i[a\cos^{a-1}(b)\sin(b)-\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3}\cos^{a-3}(b)\sin^3(b)\dots]$$
Now, equating the real and imaginary parts, we obtain:
$$\cos(ab)={a \choose 0}\cos^a(b)-{a \choose 2}\cos^{a-2}(b)\sin^2(b)+{a \choose 4}\cos^{a-4}(b)\sin^4(b)\dots$$
$$\sin(ab)={a \choose 1}\cos^{a-1}(b)\sin(b)-{a \choose 3}\cos^{a-3}(b)\sin^3(b)+{a \choose 5}\cos^{a-5}(b)\sin^5(b)\dots$$

Wow... thanks for this. It's funny how I answered your question and you answered mine

Here is another similar link.

From the complex exponential definition of sine:
$$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
We obtain the formula:
$$\sin(ab) = \frac{e^{iab} - e^{-iab}}{2i}$$
$$= \frac{(e^{ib})^a - (e^{-ib})^a}{2i}$$
$$= \frac{(\cos(b) + i\sin(b))^a - (\cos(-b) + i\sin(-b))^a}{2i}$$
$$= \frac{(\cos(b) + i\sin(b))^a - (\cos(b) - i\sin(b))^a}{2i}$$
If $a$ is an integer, then you can use the Binomial Theorem to expand the numerator, as in @Schrödinger's Cat's answer.  For example, with $a = 2$:
$$\sin(2b) = \frac{(\cos(b) + i\sin(b))^2 - (\cos(b) - i\sin(b))^2}{2i}$$
$$= \frac{(\cos(b) + i\sin(b))^2 - (\cos(b) - i\sin(b))^2}{2i}$$
$$= \frac{\cos^2(b) + 2i\cos(b)\sin(b) - \sin^2(b) - (\cos^2(b) - 2i\cos(b)\sin(b) - \sin^2(b))}{2i}$$
$$= \frac{4i\cos(b)\sin(b)}{2i}$$
$$= 2\cos(b)\sin(b)$$
Obtaining the familiar double-angle identity.
Otherwise, I don't think there's a simple formula.

Was $a=2$ just a random choice? A simpler formula is $\sin(ab) = 2 \cos(\frac{ab}{2})\sin(\frac{ab}{2})$. When $a=2$, we get the double-angle identity.
